# Can't find an internal IP address of device connected to LAN

Tags: linux, networking, lan, dhcp, embedded

Local LAN, Ubuntu laptop and Viasat Surfbeam SM2101 modem are connected to the router, wired connection. I can't find an internal IP address of satmodem connected to the router. Router only show laptop connected. I tried scan network range 192.168.1.0 - 192.168.1.255 use angry ip scanner, nmap, but they does not show satmodem. I'm not sure does it have DHCP enabled or not, there is no reset button. I tried also directly connect ethernet port of satmodem to the laptop and scan with ip scanner, also use nmap -sP 192.168.1.0/24, but it does not show it. The Network LED indicator on the modem is light means it working. I have no manual on that device, but in the configuration Guide for old version of satmodem was specified that during modem configuration, the "Support PC’s Operating System" should be configured for a static IP address of 192.168.1.2. Not sure that that's the case, as such configuration was used in quite old hardware.

Comment: What is the IP address of your linux pc?

Comment: The internal IP address of linux laptop is assigned by router, it's within 192.168.1.x

Comment: Did you try *nmap -Pn -T5 -A 192.168.1.2*?

Comment: Alternatively, the satmodem has a static address within a different network, the only othe rpossibility being *192.168.0.0*. To establish whether this is the case, give your Linux pc and address within 192.168.0.0/24, then try a scan as *nmap -Pn -sn 192.168.0.0/24*.

Answer (score 1):

Please update your question with the exact brand and model of the Satmodem.

Ideas:

1) Start `tcpdump -i eth0` (or Wireshark) on laptop, connect satmodem directly to laptop, see if it broadcasts anything (like a DHCP request).

2) You probably did that, but when scanning for IPs, make sure you have the correct address and netmask statically assigned to `eth0` (check with `ip addr`), and no other program tries (e.g. network manager) tries to interfere with that.

3) Connect satmodem directly to laptop, statically assign each of the complete [private network](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Private_network) ranges to it, scan complete range. Start with `192.168.0.0/16`.

4) Sometimes embedded devices behave differently directly after startup when the boot loader is running, e.g. they may react to different static IPs etc. Or there may be special modes you can get into by pressing the power switch for a longer time etc. This might provide an angle.

Comment: 1)I tried `sudo tcpdump -v -i eth0`, modem does not broadcasts anything, only PC communicates. 2) I've checked the connection information, all looks correct. 3) I tried scan the range `192.168.0.0/16`, only laptop IP was found after about 30min scan, but I didn't wait until it finished scanning the full range as it take too long time. I haven't tried a private address space `10.0.0.0/8`, not sure it could be within these range, this range is very broad. 4) it have no separate power button. Also, sometimes hardware are somehow "glued" to the last IP address, and only full reset can unbind it.

Comment: How did you scan? `nmap` and portscanners can set the scan interval (which is often "polite" by default). As you are scanning LAN, you can crank this up to max, this will scan much faster. Another idea: Use `ping -b` to do a broadcast ping (not all devices respond to that), or try `arping`.

Comment: First I used Zenmap with 'regular scan' profile, then tried 'Quick scan' (nmap -T4 -F), both seems slow. Also angry ip scanner with default settings.

Comment: Ok, I tried ping scan (nmap -sn), and managed to got it, 192.168.100.1